# Variable substition in jenkins pipeline config file

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to declare below parameters as variables in `jenkinsfile`.

```
 "snetwork":"projects/training26a2/global/networks/kube-shared-vpc",
 "ssubnetwork":"projects/training26a2/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/nonfrc1918-dev-nodes",
```

I am using it as shown below in my `jenkinsfile`:

```
sh "gcloud --quiet beta container --project ${jsonObj.project} clusters create ${jsonObj.cluster_name} --zone ${jsonObj.zone} --machine-type="e2-medium"  --disk-size="100"   --service-account ${jsonObj.serviceaccount}  --max-pods-per-node ${jsonObj.podspernode} --num-nodes ${jsonObj.noofnodes}  --enable-private-nodes --master-ipv4-cidr ${jsonObj.masteripv4cidr} --enable-ip-alias --network ${jsonObj.snetwork} --subnetwork ${jsonObj.ssubnetwork}
```

But this is not working for me as the value of `${jsonObj.snetwork}` is not getting substituted.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Which type of Jenkins file are you using, declarative or scripted? Can you post your pipeline skeleton?

Answer (score 1):

Should work by defining variables like this:

```
String snetwork = "projects/training26a2/global/networks/kube-shared-vpc"
String ssubnetwork = "projects/training26a2/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/nonfrc1918-dev-nodes"
```

Usage:

```
sh "--network " + snetwork + " --subnetwork " + ssubnetwork
```